# Going from numpy array to itk Image

Tags: python, numpy, itk

I have a numpy array and want to convert it into an ITK image for further processing.  How do I do this without using the PyBuffer extension to WrapITK.  I can't use that because I get a bunch of errors when compiling:

```
.../ExternalProjects/PyBuffer/itkPyBuffer.txx: In static member function ‘static PyObject* itk::PyBuffer<TImage>::GetArrayFromImage(TImage*) [with TImage = itk::Image<float, 2u>]’:
.../ExternalProjects/PyBuffer/wrap_itkPyBufferPython.cxx:1397:   instantiated from here
.../ExternalProjects/PyBuffer/itkPyBuffer.txx:64: error: cannot convert ‘int*’ to ‘npy_intp*’ in argument passing
```

I could use an idea about either how to fix the compilation errors or another way to convert my python objects.

Comment: It looks like you found the answer, http://www.polyatomic.org/2010/10/28/doing-the-obvious/. You should probably either answer the question yourself and accept it, or just delete the question so other people don't waste time on it. By the way, I did find that it probably only is a problem on 64-bit systems because of the difference in the size of `int`.

Comment: Since npy_intp has been around for so long, I figured they would have changed it in the ITK source by now if it was the problem.  I can't be the only person to come against this bug.

Comment: No, I saw one other person who came across it, but they did something slightly different - used an alternative function or some such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change

```
int dimensions[ ImageDimension ];
```

to

```
npy_intp dimensions[ ImageDimension ];
```

and recompile.

Answer (score 1):

You may be very interested in the recent SimpleITK work that is occuring.

There is much information at www.simpleitk.org.

The source code and much documentation can be found at http://www.github.com/SimpleITK.

Answer (score 0):

Clone the [PyBuffer repository](https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/itkPyBuffer) in your ITK source tree at Modules/External. Then enable it in your CMake configuration.